# Defining class members with structured bindings

Tags: c++

I would like to define class members `a`, `b` using structured bindings, in something like the following way:

```
struct AB {
  int a;
  int b;
};

class MyClass {
  public:
    MyClass(AB ab) : ab{ab} {}

  private:
    AB ab;
    const auto [a, b] = ab;
}
```

However, with gcc 9.2.0 this causes the compiler error:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
   12 |     const auto [a, b] = ab;
```

Is there some way I can rewrite this with structured bindings so that it compiles? Or must I give up using structured bindings and define each member separately:

```
  const int a = ab.a;
  const int b = ab.b;
```

Comment: Is `class MyClass : private AB` an option? This should pretty much do what you want. And you wouldn't have all data duplicated.

Comment: are you sure that your gcc compile with c++17 standard?

Comment: yes - I am compiling with `g++ --std=c++17` (`c++2a` does not work either)

Answer (score 5):

> I would like to define class members ... using structured bindings
>
> Is there some way I can rewrite this with structured bindings so that it compiles?

No. You cannot have structured bindings as members.

> Or must I give up using structured bindings and define each member separately:

That would be well-formed.

Regardless of how you declare the members, it is unclear why you'd want to have copies of the members of member as direct members. I recommend reconsidering your design.